# How to set css class to body before page load in MVC 5?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

The default class is for body is **"skin-2"**.
But when user set any skin say "skin-1" or "skin-3"to its page body class,its saved in database.When he log in next time,then that skin i.e. either "skin-1" or"skin-3" should be applied to the body.But before it get applied ,the default skin i.e. **"skin-2"** first show and then "skin-1" or "skin-3" shows.

My Homepage is:

```
<body class="skin-2">
```

My jquery code is:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (themeSelected == "PlasticBlue") {
        $('body').removeClass('skin-2')addClass('skin-1');
    }
    if (themeSelected == "Metropolis") {
        $('body').removeClass('skin-2').addClass('skin-3');
    }
});
```

Comment: You can do this in `razor view` itself instead of `document.ready` right?

Comment: can you show the controller where you get the css value from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the default `CSS` class value stored in the Database i.e `skin-2` in your case. When the user logs in get that value from the database and store it in the `ViewBag` before the View gets displayed. If the CSS value changes in the database it will as it is be passed to the body class attribute.

```
public ActionResult LogIn()
{
    @ViewBag.css= getCssClass(); // get the css class from the Database
    return View();
}
```

And in the View you can simply pass the `ViewBag` value to the body class attribute.

```
<body class="@ViewBag.css">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer